# How to use browser.storage.sync in ContentScript with webextension-polyfill

Tags: browser-extension, webextension-polyfill

I have been developing a browser extension in vaniall JS till now. I would like to use vite + Vue moving forward. Upon doing a google search I found this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/samrum/vite-plugin-web-extension) which help with this.

I'm trying to set the user preferences and save them in storage using `storage.sync`. But when I use browser.storage.sync.get, I get below error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync')

How to solve this? What is the correct way to use `storage.sync` with
[webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) or [@types/webextension-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webextension-polyfill)

Below is the code is have using vanilla js with is woring perfectly

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get({ 'testData': MyTestData }, result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to use storage.sync using webextension-polyfill

```js
import browser from "webextension-polyfill";

browser.storage.sync.set({ 'testData': MyTestData }, result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: I get `Unexpected token "export"` when using this import syntax in a content script.